# Subclassing UITableViewCell causes text and image to shift when loaded

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` because I want to explicitly set the `imageView` frame size, regardless of the size of the images I actually give it.

That being said, when my `tableView` loads, everything seems to shift after a split second. The image gets slightly larger, and the `titleLabel` and `detailLabel` both shift over closer to the image.  Have I done something wrong in my subclass?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Selected View
        self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = RGB(233, 233, 233);

        // Text Label
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        self.textLabel.opaque = YES;
        self.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = self.textLabel.textColor;

        // Detail
        self.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        self.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
        self.detailTextLabel.opaque = YES;
        self.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = self.detailTextLabel.textColor;

        // Cell
        self.opaque = YES;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    float desiredWidth = 70;
    float desiredHeight = 70;
    float leftMargin = 5;
    float topMargin = 5;

    float w=self.imageView.frame.size.width;
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    if (w>desiredWidth) {
        float widthSub = w - desiredWidth;
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(leftMargin,topMargin,desiredWidth,desiredHeight);
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x-widthSub,self.textLabel.frame.origin.y,self.textLabel.frame.size.width+widthSub,self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x-widthSub,self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width+widthSub,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are doing

```
self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
```

I really think it should be

```
self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
```

because self.selectedBackgroundView is positioned based on parent view coordinate system

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be the issue.